# Java write int to file shows "chinese" letters in file

Tags: java, file

I'm new around here.
So here's my issue:

As I said on title, the number's shown in a weird format on my file, like: "     d∟ÿ    ".

Here's my code:

```
    try
    {
        int x;
        FileOutputStream out=new FileOutputStream("numbers.txt");
        DataOutputStream st=new DataOutputStream(out);

        x=readInt();
        st.writeInt(x);

        st.close();
    }
    catch(IOException e)
    {
        System.out.println("Problem with the output file");
    }
```

How to prevent this and to actually see the int number that I've typed in ?

Comment: Don't use a DataOutputStream - this produces binary data. Use PrintWriter etc.

Comment: You use a DataOutputStream (mostly) for efficient storage of data - no conversion from bin to string and back is required.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to write a number as text, instead of binary as you have done, use PrintWriter instead.

```
try (PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter("number.txt")) {
    int x = readInt();
    pw.println(x);
}
```

To append rather than re-writing the file you can do

```
try (PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(new FileWriter("number.txt", true))) {
    int x = readInt();
    pw.println(x);
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot ! This solved my issue! What if I want a new row to be added in the file than "resetting" it every time I put a new password ?

Comment: @NikosPappas I have added how to append to a file.